# Add big green check mark to Keynote presentation

Tags: iwork, keynote

I'm using Keynote '09 for the first time, and I find myself wanting some bits of clip art or additional shapes. At the moment, I just want a big check mark. It's hard to believe that this isn't provided, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keynote doesn't really come with clip art. It is easy, however, to add images.

I did a Google Images search for `check mark`, and set the color to green. [Here are the results](http://images.google.com/images?q=check+mark&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=960&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1,ic%3aspecific,isc%3agreen&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=n5N3TZXfOYKesQPc8aS3BA&ved=0CBoQpwU) (there are many good images).

To add the image to Keynote, click See Full Size Image and click-and-drag it to your slide.

Enjoy!

Comment: Depending on the image, this might be a copyright violation. For example, some of the images in your list are from photography providers such as iStockphoto. Depending on the use case of the presentation, this might be important to know.

Answer (score 6):

Most fonts have a check mark dingbat. In a text box, type in option v to see it. Then change the color to green like you would any other text.

For additional clip at, look at the dingbat fonts already be installed on your system. Some common ones are webdings, wingdings and zapf dingbats.

Comment: that's not a check mark, it's a square root symbol

Answer (score 3):

Keynote now has several scalable and editable graphics including a check mark.

Select the shape icon, from there sort symbols or simply type in ‘check’ to select.

Change the size, color or otherwise adjust.

This applies both to macOS and iOS versions of Keynote.  iOS version shown below.

[image: checkmark]

Answer (score 1):

Add a text box. Start typing. Then press CTRL+CMD+space to bring up the characters popover. At the bottom of that popover scroll to the right until you see the ✻ category. Inside there you'll find a couple of different check mark/tick characters like ✓ and ✔︎. Once the symbol is in your document, resize it and choose a colour.